# Navigate to search community page in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, navigationmixin.navigate

I have a problem with NavigationMixin.Navigate, it redirects to Invalid Page. I think that it is because of the :term in search url. My code:

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
      type: 'comm__namedPage',
      attributes: {
        name: 'Search'
      },
      state: {
        term: this.searchStr
      }
    });
```

How can I pass that search text?

Comment: 'state' is not something you can specify on a page reference for the type  `comm__namedPage`, and 'Search' is not a supported page for that type: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_page_reference_type

Answer (score 0):

If you are redirecting to the standard search page, you'll want to do this:

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
   type: 'standard__search',
   state: {
     term: 'theTerm'
   }
});
```